# Eclipe PDE: Jump to line X and highlight it

Tags: eclipse-pde, eclipse-api

A qustion about Eclipse PDE development: I write a small plugin for Eclipse and have the following
* an [org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/ITextEditor.html)
* a line number

How can I automatically jump to that line and mark it? It's a pity that the API seems only to support offsets (see: ITextEditor.selectAndReveal()) within the document but no line numbers.

The best would be - although this doesn't work:

```
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)IDE.openEditor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage(), file, true );
editor.goto(line);
editor.markLine(line);
```

It this possible in some way? I did not find a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on the class [DetailsView](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?#xSRDEZLvYus/src/de/tobject/findbugs/view/DetailsView.java&q=de.tobject.findbugs.view%20gotoline&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=192) I found the following method.

```
private static void goToLine(IEditorPart editorPart, int lineNumber) {
  if (!(editorPart instanceof ITextEditor) || lineNumber <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) editorPart;
  IDocument document = editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(
    editor.getEditorInput());
  if (document != null) {
    IRegion lineInfo = null;
    try {
      // line count internaly starts with 0, and not with 1 like in
      // GUI
      lineInfo = document.getLineInformation(lineNumber - 1);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
      // ignored because line number may not really exist in document,
      // we guess this...
    }
    if (lineInfo != null) {
      editor.selectAndReveal(lineInfo.getOffset(), lineInfo.getLength());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though [org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/ITextEditor.java.htm) deals wiith offset, it should be able to take your line number with the `selectAndReveal()` method.

See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg13207.html) and [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg21178.html).

> Try something along the line of:

```
((ITextEditor)org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI.openInEditor(compilationUnit)).selectAndReveal(int, int);
```